# How do I stop answering questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I recently signed up to SO so I could answer questions and participate. It now appears that I am hooked, I had plans for working on personal projects today and as it turns out I have spent the whole day reading and answering questions here. Some people (like myself) lack self control when they don't have any paid work to do.

Can we have a feature where I can flag my account to disable answering questions or posting comments for a set number of hours ?

Comment: No, there is not such a feature.

Comment: hence why I tagged feature-request. I think it would be handy, Unfortunately this site is actually useful while I am working so I cant just simply drop a hosts entry like I do sometimes for reddit

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/ban-myself-button-in-user-profiles

Comment: Yes.  Assuming you have a Windows-based computer, click on the "Start" menu.  Then mouse over to "Shut Down".  In no time, you'll be looking at a black screen which should prevent you from answering questions.  I'm not sure of the exact steps with a Mac, since I don't own one, but I'm positive they have a similar feature.

Comment: @JohnnyBones unfortunately I haven't used windows in over a decade. And I do get paid to use a computer which is an unfortunate catch 22. Today I was supposed to be working on a hobby project( involving a broken Nintendo 3ds and my recently found ability to compile and run code on it )  but nope, it's 2am, I've just finished watching better call Saul and I'm back here again...

Comment: This was just a funny silly post, you cant stop yourself so you want a feature that will stop you?  What's next?  Smokers who want to quit want all stores to stop selling cigarettes so they don't smoke anymore.  Come on this is just plain old silly.

Comment: What makes this awesome is that I'm chain smoking at the moment ( and it's now 430 am and I'm still here )  I do something similar to reddit at times but I have no reason to actually be on reddit while coming to stack overflow is sometimes needed during my work or hobby time. ( while posting is not ) plus I'm getting this post downvoted to oblivion which is sort of a feat in itself since this is actually the only question that I have asked here ( the only real it related questions I ever have I usually strongly doubt that the vast majority of people could answer if I can't google it )

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [How do I prevent a Stack Overflow addiction?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91609), [How addicted to Stack Overflow are you?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11652), [How can I get help with Stack Overflow addiction?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69560), [Addiction towards Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21037) and definitely ["Ban myself" button in user profiles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32299) and [How can I ban myself?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151885)

Comment: In particular have a look at the StackApps post [No answering: prevent answering questions](http://stackapps.com/q/2079), although it's an old script and I have no idea if it still works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the sentiment is understandable, however, this feature is not really a productive way of accomplishing that. In fact, it is slightly counter-productive to the way the site works.

If you enjoy coding, you can write a user script to manage your behavior. It could use localStorage to monitor your answering behavior and provide some sort of block at some point.

Alternatively, you could design a browser extension which simply removes all questions from the page and just enable it when you feel you need to get work done. If you use chrome, it is trivial to accomplish.

But to address the title of this question, "how do I stop answering questions", to me that stands out as an addictive personality trait (which isn't a negative thing so please don't take it as an insult). Speaking to a trained therapist can provide personalized mechanisms which you can employ to help avoid getting side tracked. I know it seems overly critical, but it is basically just getting advice from someone who is classically trained in behavior patterns and ways that you can manage them.

All in all, the system was designed to prevent people from spending too much time daily answering questions (hence the 200 rep limit) so your sentiment isn't far off from the mindset here.

Comment: I like this idea, when I have something actually productive to do I have no trouble focusing , but at the moment I'm working bare minimum hours due to circumstances out of my control, and while I am hunting for a new job / contract I have plenty of time on my hands too... If I was to implement a technical solution then it would have to most likely be capable of going across multiple devices ( for example it's 330 am at the moment I'm in bed on my iPad .. )

Comment: @DamianNikodem - That is a lot of typing for an iPad :) I am not sure if the Safari browser offers an easy way to implement user scripts aside from bookmarklets. Although it requires a few extra touches per answer, it would at least be away to monitor how long you have spent. The nice thing about using a script in the browser is it will definitely be cross platform, as JavaScript is very standardized.

Comment: I'm actually thinking a packet sniffing proxy , maybe self sign my own key of this site so I can serve https to here from it and sniff contents, give myself a ban for x hours button and force it to reject any post requests to stack overflow during that time ..  I'm actually using the stack exchange app on the iPad and it's pretty neat... All I really have to do tomorrow is effectively write bash scripts for 5 hours .