# Can we separate the addictive from the fun part in SO?

Tags: discussion, gamification

I read an interesting [article](https://www.theguardian.com/media/2018/jan/23/never-get-high-on-your-own-supply-why-social-media-bosses-dont-use-social-media) today about how social media are designed to be addictive. Although I was aware of the general point before, it did make me think about addictive elements in StackOverflow (the only social media I am seriously involved in) for the first time. A quick search on SO showed, that while there is scarce, but consistent evidence that a number of SO users are [aware of those elements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275589/3356270) and some even say of themselves that the are [addicted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285665/how-do-i-stop-answering-questions/285680#285680) [to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324257/3356270) SO, there is virtually no discussion about whether or not SO is dependent on causing this kind of addiction or whether or not we can analytically separate addictive elements from the fun elements in SO gamification.

Therefore I would like to ask you three (related) questions:

1. In what sense do you think that addiction is built into SO? Is it the rep system in general (of which some say, it prevents high-quality answers)? Or are there only specific aspects of the rep system which cause people to "get hooked"? Or do you think that addiction in SO is a negligible problem?
2. Can we say that addiction and fun are coextensive, that without addictive elements SO wouldn't be fun and vice versa? Would getting rid of addictive elements, also kick out all the fun from SO and therefore dry it out from within?
3. And how about the (undoubtedly existing) usefulness of SO? At one point or another, all of us have been "saved" from despair by a good answer. Do you think this "good" part of SO is irresolvably intertwined with the "bad" and the "ugly" parts of addiction? In other words, would helpful answers not be given anymore if addiction to SO decreased? Or would reducing addictive elements improve the quality of answers?

And let me ask an equally serious question about us answering these questions: Can the addicted reliably analyze the roots of their addiction and possibly decide soberly about which parts of SO triggering highs simultaneously cause damage?

Comment: I'm not very good at counting things, but I think that these are not only more than the **one** question that makes sense to put in a post; but even more than the **three** questions that you say you are going to ask.

Comment: I believe it doesn't make sense to tear these questions apart.

Comment: I'm hooked on down voting. Y'all should try it ...

Comment: Who says that the rep system prevents high quality answers? That sounds doubtful to me.

Comment: @rene Uhuh, denial is a strong indicator for addiction.

Comment: @BDL see [this](https://vultureofcritique.wordpress.com/quotations/why-michael-richter-stopped-contributing-to-stackoverflow/), for example.

Comment: @rene (and the other unknown downvoters) I am still waiting for at least a trace of a rational argument ... Otherwise it would feel like gang vandalism.

Comment: Just don't expect a rational answer for such an absurd proposition.  Count the number of human addictions you know that are trivially cured by boredom.  Don't include the common affliction of wanting to trivialize the effort of the site contributors at their meta for kicks, no real cure for that one.

Comment: Proposition? What do you think I am proposing? The only proposition I can see myself making is discussion. Is this what you find absurd?

Comment: @HansPassant Also, what makes you think that I am not a "site contributer"? Actually I am contributing right now by asking (possibly uncomfortable) questions concerning the site. It seems, however, that some people try to reserve a monopoly on what can be asked and what not. If they succeed, the whole site would be threatened.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that the compulsive elements of the site are both an accident, and undesirable by the site.  That's just not the case.  The gamification elements are *added* to be compulsive, at least to some extent (you could make an argument that they weren't intended to be *as* compulsive as they ended up being).  That's pretty inherent to gamification as a principle.  SE isn't designed to be a game.  It's *goal* isn't to help people have fun.  The goal is to get people to contribute content.

Comment: You use the classic argument when you say *"you're addicted"*, someone says *"no, I'm not"* and then you go *"well since you deny it it must be true"* and **then** you're calling for a rational argument? It doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Servy I am not sure I understand the fine twist in your argument. You say SO is gamified (not by accident, but on purpose - I agree, but think that purposes can be debated and reverted if found problematic), but it is not designed to be a game. Could you explain please.

Comment: @kalabalik The whole *point* of adding gamification to something is to get people to engage in something that they otherwise wouldn't (or wouldn't engage in as much/long/often/etc.).  The *reason* you add gamification elements to something is because you're trying to make it, at least to some extent, compulsive.  That's the *design* of those elements.  If you realize that SO isn't a game, then why focus on making the site more "fun"?  The *goal* of the site isn't to get people to have fun, it's to create content.

Comment: @ivarni I was joking - unfortunately noone laughed. What do you expect me to do when I get an answer like rene's who does not waste a single thought in his incitement to downvote?

Comment: @Servy Still don't get that part: gamified, but not a game (what then? something more serious?). You are giving an answer to my question in a comment since you are (kinda) saying that SO would break down without the addictive part. Care to move it where it belongs?

Comment: @kalabalik You use the term gamification in your question, indicating you're familiar with the concept.  If you're not, then do some research into it, as there's a lot of information out there on the topic.

Comment: I am pretty clear about what gamification means. What is unclear is how you use the concept of "game".

Comment: @kalabalik _Still don't get that part: gamified, but not a game_ As soon as you gamify something, it doesn't magically become a game, also you don't earn or lose rep on Meta.

Comment: @George Oops, I edited the part about rep. And okay, SO is designed to be a content generating engine, not a purposeless game.

Comment: The answer by @Servy I was hoping for, is is still missing. So I will have to answer him here. The purpose of SO may not be to have fun, but to create content. If the site ever stopped to create more content, it would loose most of its users. It continues to generate content, however, because many people either think it is fun or are addicted to it (or both). While you are saying that SO was successfully designed to be addictive (compulsory) which is why it works, others (like CodeCaster below) say that they have fun using SO beyond its gamification elements ("that hunt for a good question").

Comment: Therefore I thought it would be a good idea to understand the relationship between fun and addiction, or, free will and compulsion in SO. The fact that the system is *designed* for compulsion does not mean that it has to stick to this design in the future especially if a discussion would show (I am not saying it will show) that "the community" would like to get rid of compulsory elements.

Comment: @pnuts Is there a badge for that?

Comment: Thanks for asking the question, @kalabalik. It may be broad, and it may be impossible to answer, but I think it's important to think about. Just asking the question is worthwhile.

Comment: I guess he downvotes mean that it's impossible to separate...

Answer (score 12):

> Or do you think that addiction in SO is a negligible problem?

Not negligible, no.

Sure, Stack Overflow helps a helluva lot of developers get through their day in which they ground to a halt, but on the flip side there's tons of experienced developers grinding through various review queues and question lists, separating the wheat from the chaff, while they inarguably have better things to do. One can only hope that on the grand scale this yields a net positive result, but I beg to differ.

Why they do this? Why *I* do this? It's the same as with Reddit. If one out of twenty posts gives you a chuckle, you keep scrolling through nineteen shitposts at a time to get that little kick of dopamine after seeing yet another funny cat picture.

I'm not sure what role reputation plays here. For me it's that hunt for a good question where you are the first with a decent answer that teaches not only the OP, but also later visitors something.

So: yes, some people could do with a little less Stack Overflow on any given day. It shouldn't be the first site I open on a day. I don't know whose fault it is though that it's so addictive, nor do I think Stack Overflow should (or even could) do anything against it.

Comment: Are you saying that SO would continue to be useful and fun without the rep system?

Comment: I'm saying that I don't think the reputation system is what makes it fun _for me_.