# Upload saved resume triggers a "This app isn't verified" warning from Google Drive

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, cv-import

I happened to come across `Job preferences - Saved Resume` section and decided to upload my resume. Choosing to upload it from my Google Drive, I was met with the following message:

[image: This app isn't verified. This app hasn't been verified by Google yet. Only proceed if you know and trust the developer. Back to Safety. Google hasn't reviewed this app yet and can't confirm it's authentic. Unverified apps may pose a threat to your personal data. Learn more. Go to stackoverflow.com (unsafe).]

I could go through by choosing `Go to stackoverflow.com(unsafe)`. It's a shame that Stack Overflow would be treated *unsafe*.

Is this something that Stack Overflow team has overlooked? Or is this something unfixable?

Comment: Maybe Google has a backlog of apps to review.

Comment: @BSMP - Maybe. I think it's better not to expose users to the service that currently treats SO unsafe.

Comment: investigating...

Comment: Stack Overflow is extremely unsafe. Just today it was called [addictive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362449/can-we-separate-the-addictive-from-the-fun-part-in-so). It should have the same required warnings as cigarette boxes.

Comment: @DavyM. couldn't agree more. I was fired for practices I've picked up here. I'm praised for drawing Free-Hand-Circles around things causing issues here on SO. This practice didn't go over well when we had our quarterly HR reviews when I started drawing circles on people's foreheads. Fired instantly for this practice. What gives?! this was a MVCE of why things weren't working... geesh. I since flagged  them for VLQ on glassdoor

Comment: Last week, somebody held me upside down and shook me to get loose rep out of my pocket.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

Yup, it seems like this is a [relatively new thing](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/updating-developer-identity-guidelines.html) and we need to ask for an app review.

We have already sent a request for them to review it. [Their form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification) says that "Verification process typically takes between 3 and 7 business days, but in some cases it may take longer", so it's just a matter of waiting now.

If the url where you initiate the Google Drive authentication starts with `https://stackoverflow.com/`, you can safely ignore the warning.

**UPDATE**: I've just verified that the warning is gone.

Comment: Thank you so much for being quick & responsive regarding what could be seen as a minor/none issue!